# sofware to anim .stl before importing movie in after effect cs5

Tags: 3d

im looking for a software (free ideally) and user friendly to be able to import .stl format and anim them,then import them in after effect to add logo, typo and other stuff. Now im using open slipper to convert .stl in .3ds, then passing in photoshop to create a 3d layer so that i can import them in after effect cs5 to anim them and adding others elements (logo, typo ext). but photoshop crash often on some piece that i import in 3d layer, and anim the 3d objects in after effect to really easy.

tks

Comment: Why not using _Blender_ OR export it as .obj to import it in after effects with _Element 3d_?

Comment: i  tried using blender then export .3ds and make a 3d layer in photoshop then import in efter effect but very often photoshop crash :( have looked for element 3d but a little expensive. Im trying cheetah now and i think it is ok then save .mov to put in after effect to continu to assembeland finish animation. Best solution i found for now. Tks a lot

Comment: Why not converting your comment into an answer?